# What is the syntax to properly use a variable in a Qt Qml XmlLIstModel query

Tags: xml, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

XmlListModel {
    id: ios_elementsModel
    source: "/TestCode/PositionersAndRepeaters/PositionersAndRepeaters/menuitems.xml"
    query: "/MenuItems/MenuItem"

    XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "id/number()" }
    XmlRole { name: "type"; query: "type/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "index"; query: "index/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "verbage"; query: "verbage/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "parentpageid"; query: "Parentpageid/number()" }
    XmlRole { name: "destinationpageid"; query: "destinationpageid/number()" }
```

}

I am using Qt QML (qt quick) with an XmlListModel defined above.

I have tested the above code and it returns all of the items in the xml file.

I would like to use a variable to filter the items.  Such as Parentpageid = $myselectedpage. How do you do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the XmlListModel exists to represent exactly the source xml.  If you want to have a filtered list then you have three obvious options that I can see. The first is to have the component that presents the ListModel determine which elements to show/hide(show/hide the delegate based on your criteria).  Secondly, generate a new ListModel from the XmlListModel that only contains the elements you want(This can be done in javascript but is SIGNIFIGANTLY faster if done in C++). Thirdly, have the C++ layer provide the initial ListModel and perform the filtering when building the ListModel to be used in QML.

If you are worried about memory and or processing time I highly recommend option 2/3 where the logic is done in C++.

As requested, details on creating a listmodel with JS.  To do this you need to have an existing ListModel already. Either by having created one in advance in the QML file or by using dynamic QML object creation to generate a new one. Then use the api found http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listmodel.html and append in the elements you want.

After reading a comment I finally realized you are filtering based on pages!  At this point I think your best option is to share the ListModel across all your components and have your View determine which elements to show

Comment: Can you direct me to some javascript code that might show me how to filter them.  The data will probably consist of about 150 items and will not change. So, I believe that javascript will be sufficient. However, sample js code will probably be of value should I wish to rewrite in C++.

Comment: If you are always filtering the list model on load and the xml does not change why don't you just change the xml file?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean... are you suggesting multiple xmlListmodels, one for every page instance?